# Can't pre-populate textarea fields

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that lets a user submit things like "header" and "description_1".  I take this information an build a simple one page website for them. There's a link that lets them edit the page, which reads the fields back from the database and pre-populates the form with it.  The form is pre-populated by setting the value attribute of the fields to the data pulled back from the database. This works fine for input fields (485-490 below) but it doesn't work for textarea fields (493-498 below).  I've verified that $description_1 does have the right text but setting the textarea value to this text doesn't get it to show up when the form is displayed. Does anyone know what the problem might be?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text areas work differently than other input fields. Default values are set by adding your text in between the HTML tags.

```
<textarea><? echo $description_1 ?></textarea>
```

It's been a while since I 've done this but I think you're going to run into some trickiness with carriage returns. To do that you need to convert the values with nl2br. I think it's like this:

```
<textarea><? echo nl2br($description_1) ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close, text areas are a bit different than input fields. While you set the value of an input,  you populate a text area by echoing text between the opening and closing  the text area tags.

```
<textarea><?php ehco $foo; ?></textarea>
```